# Updating model with a user chosen file path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file

In ASP.NET MVC I can make a text box for a string property (in this case representing a path to a *local* file) in the model like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyFilePathStringProperty)
```

I want to update a string property with an absolute path using a file selection box (It would have the same look and feel as HTML's `<input type="file">` tag). I'm imagining something like

```
// Pseudo code
@Html.FileUploadFor(m => m.MyFilePathStringProperty)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Doing due diligence on the internet I have found http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx but this doesn't seem like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, the file path is not sent to the server. The File is sent to the server on Post.

Here would be a simple view for uploading a file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})){ 

     <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}
```